Graph API Only Fetching My Data and Admin Pages—Are There Restrictions on Accessing Other User and Page Data?
I'm trying to use the Graph API to fetch data from other people and pages, but it only fetches my data and the pages I'm an admin of. Is it possible to do this, or has Facebook implemented restrictions ?
I’ve tested different API requests with various permissions and tokens, but the result is the same—I can only access my data and data from pages I manage.
I've watched several YouTube videos that demonstrate using the Graph API to fetch data from different sources, but many of these tutorials are a bit outdated. They suggest methods that no longer seem to work.

Access to user data always requires that user's content. And for access to data from pages you do not have admin access to, you'd need to get the Page Public Content Access feature approved for your app first.
